# How to calculate instance hours in aws?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am using free tier of AWS, I am running 3 different websites on a single Instance. what is the Instance Hours calculation techniques ?

For 24 Hours I am getting this :
[image]

Answer (score 2):

- 1 instance hour = 1 instance running for 1 hour
- The report on your question shows that your instance has been running for 23.36 Hours (~23 hours and 20 minutes).
- The forecasted month-end usage is what AWS think you will use by the end of the billing period.
- Percentages shown here represent how much ressources you used compared to how much ressources are included in the free tier.